# CAS 4.0 LDAP Won't query server

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, ldap, cas

I am in the process of setting up a CAS 4.0 server inside of docker. I'm new to CAS and Tomcat in general and could really use some help.

I have settled on this docker image as my starting point: https://github.com/panoptix-za/docker-cas
On line 19 of the Dockerfile, git clones an overlay by the same author configured for CAS LDAP authentication https://github.com/panoptix-za/cas-overlay
This overlay is placed in a tmp directory and uses maven to clean the package.

This works great and the Tomcat server is initiated as expected. Toying with cas.properties and deployerConfigContext.xml have yielded me a login screen with no visible errors in any log files. However when passed credentials nothing happens, the CAS interface reloads but no error or message is given (In the logs I do however see a ticket generated). I cannot tell if the LDAP authentication is working correctly. I have a replicated AD server in the same subnet in this cloud instance, I can use the ldapsearch command and authenticate successfully from my docker container, but CAS does not appear to work. I have not been able to figure out how to enable logging on the ldaptive module.

Here is a snippit from the /var/log/cas/cas.log (As defined in the log4j.xml)

```
 2015-07-14 15:51:47,887 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.flow.GenerateLoginTicketAction] - Generated login ticket LT-52-kPSbcZTDrF4eamfO7qwRhocCGfsdmc-cas
2015-07-14 15:51:47,887 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.flow.GenerateLoginTicketAction] - Generated login ticket LT-52-kPSbcZTDrF4eamfO7qwRhocCGfsdmc-cas
2015-07-14 15:51:47,891 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.support.CasArgumentExtractor] - Extractor generated service for: http://my.psd401.net/
2015-07-14 15:51:49,687 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.support.CasArgumentExtractor] - Extractor did not generate service.
2015-07-14 15:51:49,689 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.flow.GenerateLoginTicketAction] - Generated login ticket LT-53-gRR3tog0475cUu0l5y2BFBGYQ7W2nb-cas
2015-07-14 15:51:49,689 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.flow.GenerateLoginTicketAction] - Generated login ticket LT-53-gRR3tog0475cUu0l5y2BFBGYQ7W2nb-cas
2015-07-14 15:51:49,693 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.support.CasArgumentExtractor] - Extractor did not generate service.
2015-07-14 15:53:44,363 INFO [org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl] - Reloading registered services.
2015-07-14 15:53:44,363 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl] - Adding registered service ^(https?|imaps?)://.*
2015-07-14 15:53:44,363 INFO [org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl] - Loaded 1 services.
```

I've tried hundreds of combinations in deployerContextConfig.xml. the best results I have had are with the configurations (links below)

But neither of these appear to even try to authenticate as shown by the logs above. The page simply refreshes and no error is given in any logs or on the interface. Almost as if CAS doesn't even try.

Comment: Links to deployerContextconfigs that somewhat work here:
https://gist.github.com/kelsey9649/23f1620243ae2b6de885
and the original from the repo
https://github.com/panoptix-za/cas-overlay/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml

Answer (score 0):

My issue was my load balancer. I pre-configured the load balancer to direct all traffic to hostname/cas. This was problematic as the login button was directing to hostname/cas/cas.